# FRIENDS Table Datastore Design + App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In my application, we need to develop a FRIENDS relationship table in datastore. And of course a quick solution I've thought of would be this:

```
user     = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required=True, collection_name='user')
friend   = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required=True, collection_name='friends')
```

But, what would happen when the friend list grows to a huge number, say few thousands or more ? Will this be too inefficient ?

Performance is always a priority to us. This is very much needed, as we would have few more to follow this similar relationship design.

Please give advice on the best approach to design for FRIENDS relationship table using datastore within App Engine Python environment.

**EDIT**
Other than FRIENDS relationship, FOLLOWER relationship will be created as well. And I believe it will be very often enough all these relationship to be queries most of the time, for the reason social media oriented of my application tend to be.

For example, If I follow some users, I will get update as news feed on what they will be doing etc. And the activities will be increased over time. As for how many users, I can't answer yet as we haven't go live. But I foresee to have millions of users as we go on.

Hopefully, this would help for more specific advice or is there alternative to this approach ?

Comment: Whether something like this is efficient depends on a lot of things. How many users will you have (as an upper limit)? How many relationships will users have? How do you use with relationship within your application? How frequently are these relationships updated?

Comment: @Dan Holevoet, thanks for the questions. I've updated description. Please provide some advice, as this is very important, for us to start using the right approach to kick start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FRIENDS model (and presumably also your FOLLOWERS model) should scale well. The tricky part in your system is actually aggregating the content from all of a user's friends and followees.

Querying for a list of a user's is O(N), where N is the number of friends, due to the table you've described in your post. However, each of those queries requires another O(N) operation to retrieve content that the friend has shared. This leads to O(N^2) each time a user wants to see recent content. This particular query is bad for two reasons:

1. An O(N^2) operation isn't what you want to see in your core algorithm when designing a system for millions of users.
2. App Engine tends to limit these kinds of queries. Specifically, the `IN` keyword you'd need to use in order to grab the list of shared items won't work for more than 30 friends.

For this particular problem, I'd recommend creating another table that links each user to each piece of shared content. Something like this:

```
class SharedItems(db.Model):
  user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required=True) # logged-in user
  from = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required=True) # who shared it
  item = db.ReferenceProperty(Item, required=True) # the item itself
  posted = db.DateTimeProperty() # when it was shared
```

When it comes time to render the stream of updates, you need an O(N) query (N is the number of items you want to display) to look up all the items shared with the user (ordered by date descending). Keep N small to keep this as fast as possible.

Sharing an item requires creating O(N) `SharedItems` where N is the number of friends and followers the poster has. If this number is too large to handle in a single request, shard it out to a task queue or backend.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great suggestion. This is certainly helpful to give some extra ideas and to keep in mind on the queries efficiency. And I can relate this to many of the situations of my application as well, as we are tying to make our app to be as social media oriented as possible. Thanks again !

Comment: So when a user gets a new follower, it'll have to update the shareditems entity and insert a bunch of rows? Also if a user unfollows someone, it'll have to delete a bunch of rows from shareditems?

Answer (score 0):

propertylist are a great way to get cheap/simple indexing in GAE.
but as u have correctly identified there is a few limitations.

1. the index size of the entire entity is limited (i think currently 5000). So each propertyList value will require an index. so basically propertylist size <4999
2. serialisation of such a large propertylist is expensive!!
   bring back a 2Mb entity is slow... and will cost CPU.

if expecting a large propertyIndex then dont do it.

the alternative is to create a JOIN table that models the relationship

```
 class Friends(db.Model):
  user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required=True) # logged-in user
  from = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required=True) # who shared it
```

just a entity with 2 keys.
this allows for simple querying to find all friends for user.

```
select from friends where user = : me
```

find all user where i am the friend.

```
select from friends where friend = : me
```

since it returns a key, u can do a bulk get(keylist) to fetch the actual friends details.